# Woocommerce image alternative sizes

Tags: php, wordpress, image, woocommerce

I am modifying the woocommerce plugin and I am trying to have the product image and the thumbnails the same size (full size which is set at 400x600).

the product_thumbnails.php calls the 180x180 thumbnail however and I have not been able to find the codex for different sizes. Does anyone know how I can call the full size 400x600 image instead of the 180x180?

```
        echo apply_filters(
            'woocommerce_single_product_image_thumbnail_html',
            sprintf(
                '<a href="%s" class="%s" title="%s" data-rel="prettyPhoto[product-gallery]">%s</a>',
                esc_url( $props['url'] ),
                esc_attr( $image_class ),
                esc_attr( $props['caption'] ),
                wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, apply_filters( 'single_product_small_thumbnail_size', 'shop_thumbnail' ), 0, $props )
            ),
            $attachment_id,
            $post->ID,
            esc_attr( $image_class )
        );

        $loop++;
    }
```

I have been trying to modify this line to no avail:

```
wp_get_attachment_image( $attachment_id, apply_filters( 'single_product_small_thumbnail_size', 'shop_thumbnail' ), 0, $props )
```

Answer (score 1):

Seeing [This site](http://hookr.io/filters/single_product_small_thumbnail_size/), you can easily use the following:

> // define the single_product_small_thumbnail_size callback
>
> function filter_single_product_small_thumbnail_size( $shop_catalog ) {
>
> return 'full';
>
> }; 
>            
>   // add the filter
>
> add_filter( 'single_product_small_thumbnail_size', 'filter_single_product_small_thumbnail_size', 99, 1 );

You need to copy this in your theme `functions.php`and everywhere that WOO displays the product thumbnail it should give you the full size image instead.